# VSCODE Extension Development: Change text color after creating the treeview

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing extension and I have a couple of questions.

How can I change Icon path or text color ,label name without rebuild TreeView ?
From what I tried, when I clicked on the TreeItem, I could get the object and access to its fields. But when changing them, there was no change in the UI. I think because these TreeItems are in a different place and with the changes I made. It doesn't affect them

Comment: Yes, I believe that you have to refresh the treeView to get new icons to appear in the treeView.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Mark This won't work since after Refresh it automatically uses getChildren
and this function builds a treeview using my JSON. That is, logically, it will not change anything. We need a way that will change the data in the built tree without going into the getChildren function

Comment: You put the logic for changing the icons into the TreeItem class.  You don't say how or when you are changing icons.  In my extension the icons are determined in the TreeItem class based on a couple of conditions (like whether the file is dirty or pinned), when those things occur to the file and are detected by a listener, the tree is refreshed and this works well.  You will probably have to do something similar to change icons "on the fly".

Comment: @Mark, Thanks, I figured out it was just necessary to send the node after the changes in fire () and it worked. I still have a question how to change the color of the text

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, what do you mean by "send the node"?

Comment: @Mark `refresh(node?: vscode.TreeItem):void 
{
    this._onDidChangeTreeData.fire(node);
  }`

Comment: For how to change the TreeItem label color see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74483366/836330 - it is rather painful though.